# Setting Azure's Service tier in arm template

Tags: .net, azure, azure-rm-template

In Azure portal for SQL database there is an option under "Compute + Storage" -> "Service tier". I need to change it (to be General Purpose, for instance), but cannot to find how to do this using arm template.

Answer (score 0):

Look into SKU allowed value reference and you are good to go.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "B1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    }, ...
```